# Targeting Search Facebook language

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

How do I pull information from the Facebook Marketing API in different languages? I am using `PHP` to retrieve behaviors from FB.

```
use FacebookAds\Object\TargetingSearch;
use FacebookAds\Object\Search\TargetingSearchTypes;

$result = TargetingSearch::search(
  TargetingSearchTypes::TARGETING_CATEGORY,
  'behaviors');
```

The above code works but cannot satisfy the constraint of behaviors classified by language.

Comment: Do you want results specific _to_ a language/region, or are you just looking to get the results you already have _in_ a different language? (I guess for the latter, the `locale` parameter should do - _if_ that is implemented for this same as for regular Graph API.)

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer :) I would like to get the results I already have in a different language.

Comment: I don’t know if they provide anything for that directly in the SDK, I can only assume that this is supposed to work the same way as with Graph API, where you can specify the result language using the `locale` parameter. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/

Comment: Mh ok, and do you know how to do this in PHP ? Because i'm doing an Ajax request on my php file, so I can't load the SDK as it is shown in the documentation